# Регулярное выражение - ограничить набор и максимальное количество

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Что-то у меня не складывается с валидацией одного поля немного. Хочу ограничить максимальное количество символов до 1 и чтобы этот символ был `"1"` или `"0"`.

Использовал такие паттерны, которые ожидаемого результата не дали:

```
'/^[^1|0]{0,1}$/g'
'/[^10]{1,1}$/g'
```

Comment: Достаточно просто `^1|0$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^[^1|0]{0,1}$` находит совпадение в пустой строке или строке, состоящей из 1 любого символа, отличного от `1`, `|` и `0`.

`[^10]{1,1}$` находит совпадение в строке, состоящей из ровно 1 любого символа, отличного от `1` и `0`.

Вам нужно

```
/^[10]$/
```

[Демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/1dug3l/1)

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `[10]` - символьный класс, находит `1` или `0`
- `$` - конец строки.

Этот шаблон аналогичен (но менее эффективен) `/^(?:1|0)$/` или `/^1$|^0$/`, где вместо символьного класса используется незахватыващая подмаска с оператором ИЛИ (`|`).

Если разрешается пустая строка:

```
/^[10]?$/
```

[Демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/1dug3l/2)

Тут `?` — квантификатор, благодаря которому `[10]` может находиться 1 или 0 раз (т.е. необязателен).